# UDK Where did AnimatedCamera go?

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I'm porting a game from UT3 to UDK. One of the classes is a subclass of AnimatedCamera. However, AnimatedCamera seems to be missing from the UDK, as the compiler kindly tells me:

> Error, Superclass AnimatedCamera of class ZCam not found

Where did AnimatedCamera go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has been removed from the engine. I just looked at a recent code drop. I'm not sure why they've removed it; but, if it's important to your project I would suggest re-implementing it.

It derives from camera, which appears to be intact in the newer versions of the engine. I wish I could help more specifically, but our version of the engine is older and heavily modified and I don't directly deal with camera animations :)

But, you're not crazy, it was removed.

From what I've seen, it's just a method of playing CameraAnims. As such, moving over the functionality shouldn't be too difficult.

Good luck!